# Fill rainbow along vertical axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, filling

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> Top}, 
 FillingStyle -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> {Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][4 y]]}]
```

The above code produces a graph

[image]

However, I want it to be filled vertically. The colour gradient should be along Y-Axis, which is currently along X-Axis. Changing y to x (...`ColorData["Rainbow"][4 y]]`) doesn't solve the problem.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a solution using RegionPlot:

```
RegionPlot[y > x^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> True, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

Comment: How to make the boundary smoother?

Answer (score 8):

**Using `LinearGradientFilling`:**

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}
 , PlotStyle -> None
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Filling -> Top
 , FillingStyle -> LinearGradientFilling["Rainbow", Top]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: `LinearGradientFilling` is not available in 12.0

Comment: The other answer provides a good solution for older versions using `RegionPlot`.

Answer (score 7):

```
ParametricPlot[{x, 4 y + (1 - y) x^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> {Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]]}]
```

[image]